# Javascript Promise reject error in angular4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am getting below error, please help me how to resolve this issue

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): error at resolvePromise
>   polyfills.bundle.js:3238) at resolvePromise (polyfills.bundle.js:3209)
>   at polyfills.bundle.js:3287 at
>   ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js

Comment: Can you provide more context on your error, like the file where the error is throwned, your package.json, etc?

Comment: Post relevant code.

Comment: The problem is that you have a promise somewhere without a rejection handler, and it's getting rejected. One of the rules of promises is: If you don't pass the promise on to something else, you *must* handle rejection (and if you do, you must not [unless you can usefully convert the rejection into a resolution, or want to substitute a *different* rejection reason]). That's as much help as we can give you without the code, and I'm guessing the code would be too broad. Look for promises you don't pass on but don't have a `catch` handler (or `then` call with a 2nd arg).